# Web3.js batch request error: method.callback is not a function

Tags: web3js, batch

If I try to run the example given here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#batchrequest

With the following code:

```
const batch = new web3.BatchRequest();
batch.add(web3.eth.getBalance.request('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'latest'));

batch.execute()
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: method.callback is not a function
```

Does anybody have experience with this?

version: 
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.55"

Comment: at what line are you getting this?

Comment: Try `1.0.0-beta.34` instead.

Comment: @SanjaySB     `at node_modules/web3-providers/dist/web3-providers.cjs.js:823:22
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at node_modules/web3-providers/dist/web3-providers.cjs.js:808:23
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason (this is not documented anywhere I could find) the `request` method requires a callback function as a last parameter, as such:

```
const batch = new web3.BatchRequest();
batch.add(web3.eth.getBalance.request('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'latest', (err, res) => console.log(err, res));

batch.execute()
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: thanks, still not documented properly!

Comment: How do I apply a callback to a balanceOf function for an ERC20 token held by a particular wallet? First I add to the batch:   `batch.add(contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call.request({}, blockNumber, (err, res) => console.log(err, res)));`  

Then I call it like this  
```
await batch.execute()
  .then(res => batchRequest = res)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```  

But I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`